# Rails ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :klass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

When I run:

```
rails db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :klass
```

This is the first time I've done this on Rails 6.
Has anyone else seen this error? I can't find a reference to klass anywhere.

This is the trace:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :klass
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/table.rb:15:in `initialize'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:440:in `new'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:440:in `arel_table'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:27:in `initialize'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:118:in `new'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:118:in `create'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:467:in `relation'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:45:in `default_scoped'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:32:in `all'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:22:in `order'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:46:in `all_versions'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1282:in `load_migrated'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1400:in `block in with_advisory_lock'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `block in with_advisory_lock_connection'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:462:in `with_connection'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1416:in `with_advisory_lock_connection'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1397:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1251:in `migrate'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1086:in `up'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1061:in `migrate'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:52:in `invoke'
/Users/Jem/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Your error comes from [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/table.rb#L16). Not sure exactly why since rails >= 6.0 ships with arel 10 (it is part of rails core now) but your project is still using arel 9. Maybe try `bundle update arel`?

Comment: You were absolutely correct, thank you. I still had an arel version 9 gem in the gemfile. Removed that and it's fine.

Comment: Odd.. version 10 doesn't seem to be available anymore ?