# db:migrate - unknown keyword: :klass - arel issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I'm having an issue with upgrading an old rails app to the latest one. My knowledge of rails is limited. As far as i'm aware, i'm running ruby 3.1 with rails 7.

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :klass
/home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/table.rb:15:in `initialize'
```

I've looked around and found [this problem mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551219/rails-argumenterror-unknown-keyword-klass) however i'm already running the latest version of it i thought? I'm not 100% sure on where i'm supposed to look at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) is now a part of ActiveRecord so you no longer need the arel gem in your Gemfile. Removing that should get past this problem